# How to use google assistant on an emulator?

Tags: google-assistant

Is it possible to use Google assistant on an emulator?

Comment: Which emulator are you using?

Comment: I want to use google assistance but I don't have an android phone, Any emulator will be fine as long as it runs google assistance

Comment: @Maysara For only trying google assistant try this [guide](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine/)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I am using Linux so it will not work for me